# how to activate dropzone on icon click

Tags: javascript, jquery, file-upload, dropzone.js

I am using a image .
I would like to activate dropzone image select box on image click.
When user click on `<i class="fa fa-image" id="dzopen"></i>` user can select file by browsing and uploading image preview should display on `<div id="media-upload-previews"></div>`

```
 <i class="fa fa-image" id="dzopen"></i>
<div id="media-upload-previews">
</div>
<script>
    Dropzone.options.myAwesomeDropzone = {
        paramName: "file",
        maxFilesize: 10,
        url: 'UploadImages',
        previewsContainer: "#media-upload-previews",
        uploadMultiple: true,
        parallelUploads: 5,
        maxFiles: 20
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is working for me

```
$("i#dzopen").dropzone({
    paramName: "file",
    maxFilesize: 10,
    url: 'UploadImages',
    previewsContainer: "#media-upload-previews",
    uploadMultiple: true,
    parallelUploads: 5,
    maxFiles: 20,
    acceptedFiles: "image/*,audio/*,video/*",
    init: function () {
        this.on("success", function (file, responseText) {
            alert(file);
            alert(responseText);
           console.log(file);
        });
        this.on("thumbnail", function (file, dataUrl) {
            $('#media-upload-previews').append('<img src="' + dataUrl + '" width="50" height="50" alt="">');
        });
        this.on("removedfile", function (file) {});
        this.on("complete", function (file) {
            alert(file);
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

you can wrapp your code in to jquery click event like this

```
$(document).on("click", "#dzopen", function(){
   //initilize your dropzone here .
});
```

Comment: I have done it here please see http://jsfiddle.net/xrcwrn/y8697re4/ Now trying to see only customize image